# NullPointerException when parsing XML file

Tags: java, xml, parsing

I have this XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<music>
  <artist name="Eminem">
    <album title="Recovery" year="2010" art="cover.png">
      <song title="Cold Wind Blows" />
      <song title="Talkin' 2 Myself"/>
      <song title="On Fire"/>
    </album>
  </artist>
</music>
```

I parse it with this code:

```
// Get child elements of root
NodeList artistList = document.getElementsByTagName("artist");

for(int i = 0; i < artistList.getLength(); i++)
{
    Node artistNode = artistList.item(i);

    if(artistNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
    {
        // Album list
        NodeList albumList = artistNode.getChildNodes();

        // Get artist name
        String artistName = artistNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();

        for(int j = 0; j < albumList.getLength(); j++)
        {
            Node albumNode = albumList.item(j).getNextSibling();

            String albumTitle = albumNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title").getNodeValue();
            String albumYear = albumNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("year").getNodeValue();
            String albumArt = albumNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("art").getNodeValue();

            System.out.println(artistName+albumTitle+albumYear+albumArt);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out the attribute values just fine. However, when `j` is `1`, I get the `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
String albumTitle = albumNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title").getNodeValue();
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I be parsing it a different way with less for loops? I think I'm going to need another loop to get the song information.

Any help would be appreciated!

Full stack trace:

```
EminemRecovery2010cover.png
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at songlibrary.SongList.buildSongList(SongList.java:69)
    at app.Main.main(Main.java:37)
    ... 11 more
Exception running application app.Main
```

Comment: Post your exact exception with full stack trace.

Comment: `Node albumNode = albumList.item(j).getNextSibling();` Why `getNextSibling`? You haven't finished processing this one. (probably remained so from a prev incarnation of the cycle as a `while`?)

Comment: How else am I supposed to get the next `album`? I know I still have to process the song titles. I just wanted this to work first. I don't understand what you mean by your statement in parenthesis.

Comment: If I take out `getNextSibling()`, then it doesn't even read it the first time.

Comment: You're assuming that `albumList` has only elements, but it has text nodes as well.  See the duplicate link for further details.